# 4-Way MergeSort Challenge - Python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort, array-merge

I'm trying to write a MergeSort function that splits the array into 4 arrays and not into 2 like the regular MergeSort..

I tried to follow the 2-way mergeSort and implement it to the 4-way but I keep getting stuck in recursive calls and I can't understand where's the problem..

I wrote a merge_sort_4 function that calls itself 4 times and merge4 function that should merge 4 arrays and not 2.

I know some people in my class solved it with 3 calls to the regular Merge function but I think it kinda misses the point of this challenge..

If the only way of solving it is by using the regular Merge please tell me, if not, please help me find the problem

Here's my code

```
def merge_sort_4(lst, start, end):
    if start < end:
        quarter1 = (start + end) // 4
        quarter2 = (start + end) // 2
        quarter3 = (end - quarter1 - 1)

        merge_sort_4(lst, start, quarter1)
        merge_sort_4(lst, quarter1 + 1, quarter2)
        merge_sort_4(lst, quarter2 + 1, quarter3)
        merge_sort_4(lst, quarter3 + 1, end)

        merge4(lst, start, quarter1, quarter2, quarter3, end)


def merge4(lst, start, q1, q2, q3, end):
    first_q_list = lst[start:q1 + 1]
    sec_q_list = lst[q1 + 1:q2 + 1]
    third_q_list = lst[q2 + 1:q3 + 1]
    last_q_list = lst[q3 + 1:end + 1]

    first_q_list.append(float('inf'))
    sec_q_list.append(float('inf'))
    third_q_list.append(float('inf'))
    last_q_list.append(float('inf'))

    i = 0  # first sublist index
    j = 0  # sec sublist index
    m = 0  # third sublist index
    n = 0  # last sublist index

    for k in range(start, end + 1):
        if first_q_list[i] <= sec_q_list[j] and first_q_list[i] <= third_q_list[m] and first_q_list[i] <= last_q_list[
        n]:
            lst[k] = first_q_list[i]
            i += 1

        elif sec_q_list[j] <= third_q_list[m] and sec_q_list[j] <= last_q_list[n]:
            lst[k] = sec_q_list[j]
            j += 1

        elif third_q_list[m] <= last_q_list[n]:
            lst[k] = third_q_list[m]
            m += 1
        else:
            lst[k] = last_q_list[n]
            n += 1
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you know it doesn't work? Have you walked through the code or tested any parts in isolation? Do you have any suspicions about what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with using sentinel values (float('inf')). Consider the case when the ends of multiple runs have been reached, for example when first_q_list[i] == sec_q_list[j] == float('inf'), in which case the float('inf') at first_q_list[i] is copied to lst[k] and *i* is incremented beyond the end of first_q_list[].

The code needs to check for reaching the end of a run each time it copies an element, and if so, drop down to a 3 way merge of the remaining runs. Later dropping to 2 way merge and then finally a copy of the rest of the one remaining run.

The code could be improved, consider the case where third_q_lst[] or last_q_lst[] has the smallest element, it takes 6 compares to get to those cases. By using nested if + else, this can be reduced to just 3 compares along any path to determine which run has the smallest element. Example for 3 way merge to find smallest of a, b, c, with only 2 compares for any of the 3 possible cases:

```
    if(a <= b)
        if(a <= c)
            a is smallest
        else
            c is smallest
    else
        if(b <= c)
            b is smallest
        else
            c is smallest
```

---

Link to java example of a 4 way top down hybrid merge sort + insertion sort (for small runs). I haven't bothered porting it to Python because Python is so slow, and due to Python being an interpretive language, 4 way merge sort would probably be slower in Python than 2 way (with a compiled language, 4 way is about 15% faster than 2 way).

[How can I implement the Merge Sort algorithm with 4-way partition without the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840901/55842481#55842481)

Comment: The whole point of using `float('inf')` as a sentinel is that each list will be automatically be removed from being a contender for the smallest value when it's exhausted, without needing any change to the logic.  That's unlikely to be the whole problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom - the compare is <=, and float('inf') <= float('inf') is true. Using sentinels like this will work for 2 way merge because the outer loop that increments `k` exits just as the ends of both runs is reached. For 4 way merge it fails because the ends of two runs will reached before the merge is completed, due to the remaining 2 runs not being exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have some ideas about things that are probably wrong here, but you've not really given much indication of what help you need, so first I want to point you in the right direction for how to figure this out yourself.

Before you even write any code to go inside `merge4` and `merge_sort_4`, can you describe what are their preconditions and postconditions? I.e., what do you require to be true before one of them is called, both about the state of the list and the arguments passed to it? What is its job? What does it guarantee to have done when it has finished? What values can `start` have, and what values can `end` have?

I'm hoping that you're going to describe some constraints such as that `0 <= start <= end < len(lst)` for calling `merge_sort_4` and that `0 <= start <= q1 <= q2 <= q3 <= end <= len(lst)` for calling `merge4`, and that `merge4` requires the four sublists to be sorted and will guarantee that the entire range from `list` index `start` to `end` is sorted.

Now - are those things actually true? Can you walk through the code with example values and see what would happen? Can you add assertions into the algorithm to catch the first time one of them isn't true? Can you test the pieces of the algorithm separately on small pieces of test data to see if they behave as you expect?

Try and see if you can figure it out on your own, but if not, here's one place I suggest you start looking...

...

...

I would expect that `quarter1`, `quarter2` and `quarter3` should all fall within the range of `start` to `end` but I think the calculations you have there might not be doing what you expect. Try some different values of `start` and `end` and see if you are surprised what comes out.